# Remove Space Between Header and Unordered List (HTML) in VBA Email

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm using VBA in Excel to generate an email. However, I end up with an annoying white space between my `<h3>` and `<ul>`. I've looked and tried many different solutions, like changing the padding/margin attributes, but I'm still always left with my white space:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using in my HTML body. I'm sure it's generally messy, but I'm trying to solve one problem at a time.

```
    .HTMLBody = "<Body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                "Here is the latest status for all ITRC breaks, by product. This report is generated using data pulled on " & Format(LastMonday(Date), "m/d") & ".</body>" & _
                RangetoHTML(rng_Summary) & _
                "<Body style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>*allows are excluded from Avg. Age of Breaks calculation</Body>" & _
                "<h3><u>MANAGEMENT SUMMARY</u></h3>" & _
                "<ul style=margin-top:-30px;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                    "<li><u><b>Total # of Breaks</u></b> - " & " " & str_total_breaks_complete & "</li>" & _
                    "<li><u><b>Average Age of Breaks</u></b> - " & " " & str_avg_age_complete & "</li>" & _
                    "<li><u><b># of Breaks > 90 Days</u></b> - " & " " & str_breaks_GT90_complete & "</li>" & _
                    "<li><u><b>Breaks w/o Remedies >30 Days</u></b> - " & no_rmdy_GT30_count & " " & str_GT30_final & final_list_GT30 & "</li>" & _
                    "<li><u><b>Overdue Remedies</u></b> - " & overdue_rmdy_count & " " & str_overdue_final & final_list_OD & "</li>" & _
                    "<li><u><b>Allows Expired</u></b> - " & allows_expired_count & " " & str_exp_final & final_list_AX & "</li>" & _
                    "<li><u><b>Top CPs by Avg. Break Age</u></b>" & final_list_TopCPs & "</li>" & _
                "</ul>" & _
                "<img src=cid:" & Replace(ageChart_img, " ", "%20") & ">" & "<img src=cid:" & Replace(totalBreak_img, " ", "%20") & ">"
    .Display 'CHANGE THIS to .Display/.Send if you want to test/send
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-bottom: 0;` to your `h3`.

```
<h3 style='margin-bottom: 0;'><u>MANAGEMENT SUMMARY</u></h3>
```

Comment: Still left with the blank space. Also, why would there be single quotes here if the whole thing is one giant string? For example, when setting the style for my `<ul>`, I didn't use single quotes there.

Comment: To all browsers, single vs double quotes used in the declaration of attributes are indistinguishable, and will allow you to use spaces. (And provides a level of security vs not using quotes) 
Also, it's worth noting that ul has a default margin as well. Try setting the style on the ul node to have `margin:0`.

Comment: Still no luck. In fact, if I do `margin:0` and not `margin-top:0`, it breaks the whole list.